# Format LLama 2 Output is not parsed correctly

Tags: langchain, llama, llama-cpp-python

I've encountered difficulties in obtaining a solution to my inquiry after multiple attempts. I'm currently utilizing LLama 2 in conjunction with LangChain for the first time. The challenge I'm facing pertains to extracting the response from LLama in the form of a JSON or a list. I've made attempts to include this requirement within the prompt, but unfortunately, it hasn't yielded the desired outcome. Additionally, I've experimented with implementing the `output_parser` feature from LangChain, yet it hasn't produced the intended results either. Provided below is the code I've employed.

```
from langchain.output_parsers import CommaSeparatedListOutputParser
output_parser = CommaSeparatedListOutputParser()
format_instructions = output_parser.get_format_instructions()
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template="Extract a contextual keywords for this product title: {product_title}.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{format_instructions}",
    input_variables=["product_title"],
    partial_variables={"format_instructions": format_instructions}
)
question = prompt.format(product_title="Trottinette électrique pure air pro 2ème gén")
output=llm(question)
output_parser.parse(output)
print(output)
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to exclusively retrieve the response from my queries, eliminating any extraneous generated sentences such as "Sure, ..." or "Your Keywords are..."? Essentially, I'm looking to capture solely the list of items that I've specified.

Comment: what llm model you are using..

Comment: Hi, I am using this one
repo = "TheBloke/Llama-2-13B-chat-GGML"
model_name = "llama-2-13b-chat.ggmlv3.q6_K.bin"

Comment: is it ok for you to use other model, because every model  has different format of response

Comment: But I want to use LLama2? Is not possible with it ?

Comment: could you also share few outputs for different product title.. let me see that first..